# Algorithm: write if-then-return or else-return in one line?

Tags: algorithms, algorithm2e

I can easily generate the following algorithm statements using `algorithm2e` package. As can be seen from the image, `return` statement (should hold for other statements too) will be placed in a new line even it is very short. How can I write `if-then-return` or `else-return` in one line?

[image]

P.S. the code to generate the above is as follows:

```
... ...
\uIf{$\max_{\mathcal{AV}} > \theta_5$}
{
    \Return the tracklet with $\max_{\mathcal{AV}}$.
}
\Else
{
    \Return no speaker.
}   
... ...
```

Comment: With this type of notation, your algorithm may become ambiguous...

Comment: @PaulGaborit What kind of ambiguity?

Comment: Try with several if-then structures followed by one else line...

Comment: @PaulGaborit I think there is no problem here because `else` will be aligned with its corresponding `if`.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use `\lIf` instead of `\uIf` and `\lElse` instead of `\Else`.

MWE

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\lIf{$\max_{\mathcal{AV}} > \theta_5$}
{
    \Return the tracklet with $\max_{\mathcal{AV}}$.
}
\lElse
{
    \Return no speaker.
}  
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

---

### EDIT

If you don't want to print the semicolon at the end of each line, simply issue the command

```
\DontPrintSemicolon
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\DontPrintSemicolon
\lIf{$\max_{\mathcal{AV}} > \theta_5$}
{
    \Return the tracklet with $\max_{\mathcal{AV}}$.
}
\lElse
{
    \Return no speaker.
}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: I just noticed that there will be an extra `;` on each line. Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: @herohuyongtao See the edit

Comment: @herohuyongtao You're welcome